# I made a registration coding for my program where I store the registered student data inside a text.file

Tags: python

and I want to make a login system that uses this data to let the registered to be able to log in I tried to make one but couldn't, this is my registration coding

```
 print("Enter your details here:\n")

   student_name = input("Enter Your Username: ")
   student_id = input("Enter Your ID: ")
   student_email = input("Enter Your Email Address: ")
   student_password = input("Enter Your Password: ")

   f = open("students.txt", "a")
   f.write("\n"+student_name+","+student_id+","+student_email+","+student_password)
   f.close()
   print("\n\t\t\t\tLoading...")
   time.sleep(2)
   name=input("You have finished your registration successfuly!! please press Enter to exit...:")
   print("\n\t\t\t\tExiting...")
   time.sleep(2)
   exit()
```

Comment: "I tried, but I couldn't" is not a question. Posting the same question after it was closed isn't helpful. You need to show your code and ask specific question. Check [ask] and about [homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Answer (score 1):

Whenever storing a data in a file always use a dictionary or a list as these easily mutable.

Use any of the two given format to store the data

```
{'name':bot1,'std_Id':1234,'email':@mail,'pass':password}
[bot1,1234,@mail,password]
```

Now comes the main code:

```
f=open('students.txt','r')
stdId=input('StudentId: ')
pass=input('Password: ')
r=f.read()

#searching the file for the student ID and password
for match in r:
    if r[1]==stdId: #use this if the data is stored in list
        if r[3]==pass:
            print('Login Successful')
        else:
            print('Incorrect Password')
    else:
        print('User not Found')
f.close
```

**Explanation:** Open the file in read mode and then store the data in a variable and then iterate through the file searching for the required data. Here I searched for the second index of the instantaneous data to match it with the given stdID.